# Vscode auto add line break to vue html elements

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

When I save this:

```
<template>
    <div> <div></div> </div>
</template>
```

VSCode auto formats the code to this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And ESLint only allows elements with a single child element on the same line, so I am always having this kind of error:

```
https://google.com/#q=prettier%2Fprettier  Replace `⏎················<router-view></router-view>⏎···········` with `·<router-view></router-view>`
```

How can I fix this so that when saving files, vscode don't add new line breaks?

Comment: maybe turn off vscode auto formatting and let eslint handle it?